# How to upload images with data in one form CI with Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I create a form for adding an advertisement, where you enter a few text inputs, and under them a place with adding photos and if it was just adding photos without reloading the page - it worked, I just selected photos and sent the entire form with one button, uploaded photos to the server and I added photo names to the database. But I would like this form to be more useful and to preview these photos before sending the entire form, so I added the Ajax script. And the problem is that when you choose photos and upload them to the server I do not know how to transfer them to the main form.

I tried to add `$this->create($photos)` at the end of the upload function and pick them up in the create function. I pass them on, but as soon as Ajax has reloaded the first page when he uploads it. When I fill in the form's text fields and press send the form, then $ photos is NULL and I don't know how to transfer and save this data in the database? How do you make it work?

```
public function create()
    {

        if ( !empty( $_POST ) )
        {

            if ( $this->form_validation->run( 'site_ads_create' ) == true )
            {
                $activate_code = random_string();

                if ( logged_in() == true ) 
                {
                $data = array(
                    'title' => $this->input->post( 'title' , true ),
                    'description' => $this->input->post( 'description' , true ),
                    'category_id' => $this->input->post( 'subcat' , true ),
                    'city_id' => $this->input->post( 'city_id' , true ),
                    'price' => $this->input->post( 'price' , true ),
                    'contact' => $this->input->post( 'contact' , true ),
                    'email' => $this->session->userdata( 'email' ),
                    'phone' => $this->input->post( 'phone' , true ),
                    'user_ip' => getUserIpAddr(),
                    'created' => time(),
                    'active' => 1,



                );

                }
                else
                {
                $data = array(
                    'title' => $this->input->post( 'title' , true ),
                    'description' => $this->input->post( 'description' , true ),
                    'category_id' => $this->input->post( 'subcat' , true ),
                    'city_id' => $this->input->post( 'city_id' , true ),
                    'price' => $this->input->post( 'price' , true ),
                    'contact' => $this->input->post( 'contact' , true ),
                    'email' => $this->input->post( 'email' , true ),
                    'phone' => $this->input->post( 'phone' , true ),
                    'user_ip' => getUserIpAddr(),
                    'created' => time(),
                    'active' => 0,
                    'activate_code' => $activate_code,


                );  

                }

                $add = $this->Site_model->create( 'ads' , $data );

                $this->session->set_flashdata( 'alert' , 'Ogłoszenie zostało dodane.' );
                //redirect( '/dodaj-ogloszenie' );

            }
            else
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata( 'alert' , validation_errors() );
                //refresh();
            }

        }

        $data['cities'] = $this->Site_model->get_cities('cities', 'name', 'asc');
        $data['categories'] = $this->Site_model->get_categories();
        $this->load->view( 'create' , $data );

    }
```

upload function

```
public function upload()
    {

if($_FILES["files"]["name"] != '')
  {
   $output = '';

        $path = BASEPATH . '../images/'. date('y').'_'.date('m').'/';

        if ( !file_exists( $path ) )
                {
                    mkdir( $path , 0777 );
                }

   $config['upload_path'] = 'images/'. date('y').'_'.date('m').'/'; 
   $config["allowed_types"] = 'gif|jpg|png';
   $this->load->library('upload', $config);
   $this->upload->initialize($config);
   for($count = 0; $count<count($_FILES["files"]["name"]); $count++)
   {
    $_FILES["file"]["name"] = $_FILES["files"]["name"][$count];
    $_FILES["file"]["type"] = $_FILES["files"]["type"][$count];
    $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] = $_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$count];
    $_FILES["file"]["error"] = $_FILES["files"]["error"][$count];
    $_FILES["file"]["size"] = $_FILES["files"]["size"][$count];
    if($this->upload->do_upload('file'))
    {
     $data = $this->upload->data();
     $output .= '
     <div class="col-md-3">
      <img src="'.base_url().'images/'. date('y').'_'.date('m').'/'.$data["file_name"].'" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" />
     </div>
     ';
     $photos[] = $this->upload->data();
    }
   }
   echo $output;   
  }
}
```

and a piece of the form with the ajax script

```
<form method='post' action='<?php echo base_url();?>ads/create' enctype='multipart/form-data'>

...

<div class="container">
 <br /><br /><br />
 <h3 align="center">Upload Multiple Files in Codeigniter using Ajax JQuery</h3><br />

 <div class="col-md-6" align="right">
  <label>Select Multiple Files</label>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-6">
  <input type="file" name="files" id="files" multiple />
 </div>
 <div style="clear:both"></div>
 <br />
 <br />
 <div id="uploaded_images"></div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#files').change(function(){
  var files = $('#files')[0].files;
  var error = '';
  var form_data = new FormData();
  for(var count = 0; count<files.length; count++)
  {
   var name = files[count].name;
   var extension = name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
   if(jQuery.inArray(extension, ['gif','png','jpg','jpeg']) == -1)
   {
    error += "Invalid " + count + " Image File"
   }
   else
   {
    form_data.append("files[]", files[count]);
   }
  }
  if(error == '')
  {
   $.ajax({
    url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>ads/upload", 
    method:"POST",
    data:form_data,
    contentType:false,
    cache:false,
    processData:false,
    beforeSend:function()
    {
     $('#uploaded_images').html("<label class='text-success'>Uploading...</label>");
    },
    success:function(data)
    {
     $('#uploaded_images').html(data);
     $('#files').val('');
    }
   })
  }
  else
  {
   alert(error);
  }
 });
});
</script>

  <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: You can either create a session and store uploaded image name in it, then in your main form you can get the image name and show them accordingly or you can store image name in another temporary table and then show it in your main form

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preview image before upload, use FileReader to do that. This is the code,

```
 function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

//imgInp is ID form upload file
$("#imgInp").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```